# How to populate listbox from linked table?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I am working with a database that has an Excel table.

I created a form and want to populate a listbox with the contents of the linked table when the form loads.

Comment: Just use the table as row source. What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure where to start. I am in just in the beginning stages of learning VBA and have watched a few tutorials but couldn't find anything relevant online.

Comment: Okay so I did get it working and can populate the listbox with the table data. I used the following code:.                     Listbox.rowsource = "SELECT tablename.fieldname FROM tablename"

Comment: Good! You learn much more by trying things and reading documentation or examples than by asking questions. You can post this as answer, and later accept that answer, to resolve your question.

Comment: I definitely find that when I have something specific to achieve it helps me learn a language faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andre I found a working solution which is shown below:

Listbox.rowsource = "SELECT tablename.fieldname FROM tablename"

This pulls record(s) from my table and shows them in the listbox. For simplicity sake I only included a single column name but the actual code I used included 4 columns.